# Initial Conditions Solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Prove that $ y_1(x) = 1 − x^2$ and $y_2(x) = x$ cannot both be solutions of the differential equation $$y''(x) + p(x)y + q(x) = 0$$ for $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ continuous on $[0, 1]$.

Also, Find the unique solution $x(t)$ of the non homogeneous linear system
$$\frac{\operatorname{d}x}{\operatorname{d}t} =\pmatrix{−1& 3\\−2& 4} x +\pmatrix{4e^{−3t}\\1e^{−3t}}$$
that satisfies the initial condition, $x(0) = \pmatrix{1\\-2}$.

Comment: Can you separate these into two problems and please show your work and where you are stuck?

Comment: The rule of this forum is: one question per post; you've got two (completely unrelated to each other), so don't be surprised if your question gets closed.

Comment: Don't edit to remove the question after it has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ continuous on $[−1, 5]$.

   If $ y_1(x) = 1 − x$ solves the equation, then substitution into
   equation gives $$0 + p(x)(1-x) + q(x) = 0$$ i.e.  $q(x)=(x-1)p(x)$

   If $y_2(x) = x^3$ solves the equation, then substitution into
   equation gives $$6x + p(x)x^3 + q(x) = 0$$ Substitute
   $q(x)=(x-1)p(x)$ to get $$6x + p(x)x^3 + (x-1)p(x) = 0$$ $$p(x) =
       -\frac{6x}{x^3 + x-1}$$

   Note that the denominator changes sign between $0$ and $1$, i.e. the
   denominator has a zero in $[0,1]\subset [-1,5]$. Therefore $p(x)$
   has a pole in $[-1,5]$, i.e. not continuous $[-1,5]$. Thus, we got a
   contradicttion to the fact that $p(x)$ is continuous, therefore
   $y_1$, $y_2$ cannot both be the solution to the given equation.

---

2. First, find the solution to the homogeneous problem  $$\frac{dx}{dt}
   =\pmatrix{−10& 6\\−12& 7} x$$ i.e. find that $A=\pmatrix{−10& 6\\−12& 7}$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1=-2$ and $\lambda_2=-1$ and corresponding eigenvectors $v_1=\pmatrix{3\\4}$ and $v_2=\pmatrix{2\\3}$

   The solution to the homogeneous problem is therefore 
   $$x(t)=c_1\pmatrix{3\\4}e^{-2t} + c_2\pmatrix{2\\3}e^{-t}$$

   To find the solution to the inhomogeneous problem

   $$\frac{dx}{dt} =\pmatrix{−10& 6\\−12& 7} x
       +\pmatrix{10\\18}e^{−3t}$$ assume the solution of the form $\pmatrix{a\\b}e^{−3t}$, substitute into equation to get

   $$-3\pmatrix{a\\b}e^{−3t} -\pmatrix{−10& 6\\−12& 7}
       \pmatrix{a\\b}e^{−3t} \\=
       -3\pmatrix{a\\b}e^{−3t} -\pmatrix{−10a+ 6b\\−12a+ 7b} e^{−3t} \\= \pmatrix{7a- 6b\\12a- 10b} e^{−3t} 
       =\pmatrix{10\\18}e^{−3t}$$

   Solve $$\pmatrix{7& -6\\12&- 10}\pmatrix{a\\b}=\pmatrix{10\\18}$$ to
   get $\pmatrix{a\\b}=\pmatrix{4\\3}$, i.e. the solution to
   inhomogeneous problem is given by

   $$x(t)= c_1\pmatrix{3\\4}e^{-2t} +c_2 \pmatrix{2\\3}e^{-t}+
       \pmatrix{4\\3}e^{−3t}$$ Using initial condition $$x(0)=
       c_1\pmatrix{3\\4} +c_2 \pmatrix{2\\3}+
       \pmatrix{4\\3}=\pmatrix{1\\-2}$$  one get $c_1=1$, $c_2=-3$. Thus
   $$x(t)= \pmatrix{3\\4}e^{-2t} -3 \pmatrix{2\\3}e^{-t}+
       \pmatrix{4\\3}e^{−3t}$$

Answer (score 1):

1- The wronskian of $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$ is $W(x)=y_{1}y'_{2}-y'_{1}y_{2}$ which gives us $W(x)=(1-x)(3x^{2})+x^{3}$. We have $W(0)=0$. Hence by Abel's formula ($W(x)=c\exp(-\int\frac{1}{p(x)})dx$) we get $c=0$. Therefore $W=0$ on any interval containing zero. Thus $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$ are linearly dependent on your interval and can not construct a fundamental set of solutions.

2- Use the following formula for non-homogeneous linear systems $X'(t)=AX(t)+b(t)$ with $X(0)=X_{0}$:
$$
X(t)=e^{At}X_{0}+e^{At}\int_{0}^{t}e^{-As}b(s)ds.
$$